# Justifying $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\ \mathrm{d}x$ for complex values

Tags: complex-analysis, gaussian-integral

I have searched and failed to find a rigorous proof showing that
$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}$$
is true for  $\Re(a)=0$ and $\Im(a)\neq0$. For example, why does
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ix^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i}}
$$
and does one need to invoke contour integration to show this? Or is the following technique valid:

Suppose $\Re (b)>0$ and $a$ is complex; then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\ \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{b\to0}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a+ b)x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{b\to0}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a+b}}.
$$

I have an idea for contour integration but is there any way to justify this with real analysis? If not I would very much appreciate a hint for the complex analytic approach. Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for rigor, the first thing to do is rigorously define what the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ix^2}\,dx$ on the left means, and also decide which square root of $\pi/i$ you're taking on the right. As things stand, this is a little like asking for a rigorous proof that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n=-1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra I will formulate the question another way. Given that $\int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)\ \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$, we can conclude $\Re\int_0^\infty e^{ix^2}\ \mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$. Why is it that this integral, given the context I have just presented, is still identical to the aforementioned result? That is, why can we set $a=i$ in the OP to arrive at the same result for the Fresnel integral?

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ is a pure imaginary number, using contour integration $$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\, dx = e^{i\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{\frac \pi {4a}}$$ (have a look [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph215/Gaussian.pdf) for the proof).

Where the problem starts to be more difficult is to establish that
$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-(a+ib)x^2}\, dx =\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}} e^{-\frac{i}{2} \arg (a+i b)}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers

Comment: Claude, the link to the proof its missing.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri. Sorry for that ! I had a typo